# Should a change in XML root element change the signature value for a sub element?

Tags: xml, security, apache-camel, xml-signature

I have tried to produce a detached XML signed document with camel. I have noticed that if I tamper name of the namespaces the document gets invalid. E.g. changing from "soap" to "soap1" namespace makes the document invalid. I get an:

```
org.apache.camel.component.xmlsecurity.api.XmlSignatureInvalidValueException: 
           Signature validation failed. The signature value could not be 
           validated by the public key. Either the message has been 
           tampered or the public key is not correct.
```

Should it be like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <anotherSample attr="1234"/>
        <sample ID="sampleID"/>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#sampleID">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>....</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>...</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>....</ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Yes this is correct.tampering with the namespace means you tamper with the message thus signature is invalid. The whole document is used for digital signature.

Comment: It seems I was under the wrong impression that the signing ignores what happens outside the signed element <sample>. But that is not correct since it would allow XML wrapping attacks.

Comment: It depends on the canonicalization algorithm used in ds:SignedInfo. If you use an "Exclusive" Canonicalization (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n/), sub elements do not inherit the namespaces from the parents.

Comment: That's exactly what I used in order to be more flexible with anything that is being changed to the ancestor/sibling nodes except of course for the referenced <sample> node. Thanks again @Moez for your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Canonical XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments): `By virtue of the XPath data model, XML canonicalization is namespace-aware.` So yes, changing the namespace should cause the signature to change.